# Meu projeto Laravel não enxerga meu arquivo Javascript

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

A Estrutura do meu projeto é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pagina de Layout principal é esse, é aqui onde recebo o arquivo vue, axios e o app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <title>Administração de Imóveis</title>

     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <style>
         body { padding-top: 70px; }
     </style>
 </head>

 <body><!--O id do Vue.JS -->
<div>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="navbar-header">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     </button>
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Início</a>
                 </div>
                 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                         <li><a href="">Todos</a></li>
                         <li><a href="">Apartamentos</a></li>
                         <li><a href="">Casas</a></li>
                         <li><a href="">Kitnet</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </nav>
         <div class="container">
             @yield('content')
         </div>

 </div>
 <script src="{{asset('lib/vue/dist/vue.js')}}"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('lib/axios/dist/axios.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('lib/axios/jquery/dist/jquery.js')}}"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('lib/app.js')}}"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Essa é a pagina

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

      <div id="crud" class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Lista de Imoveis</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-7">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Novo  Imovel</a>

              <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                  <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Descrição</th>
                          <th colspan="2">&nbsp</th>
                        </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="dado in dados" >
                      <td width="10px">1</td>
                      <td>descrição</td>
                      <td width="10px">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-success">Editar</a>
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn- btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <pre>
              @{{ data }}
            </pre>
          </div>

      </div>
@endsection
```

Onde será que errei?

Comment: Verifique e aparece algum erro no console do navegador. Existe a pasta lib dentro de `resources/assets`?

Comment: Talvez o problema não seja esse @AndréLuizdeGusmão. Pelo que entendo do Laravel, os arquivos deverão estar dentro da pasta `public/js`. Não seria o caso de o AP não ter rodado o gulp ou npm?

Comment: Qual é a versão do Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

O Navegador não conseguirá ler os assets que estão na pasta `resources`, e sim os arquivos da pasta `public`.

Você deve entender que os assests da pasta `resources` são usados para você poder organizar melhor o seu projeto, e que o Laravel por sua vez usa por padrão o [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix) para poder compilar, minificar ou unir aquivos, que serão enviados para a pasta `public`.

Se deseja usar diretamente os arquivos, apenas os coloque na pasta `public`, mas dependendo do projeto será melhor trabalhar com os recursos oferecidos pelo Laravel Mix citado acima.

Vale a pena dar uma lida no link.